# OnTriggerEnter2d unity not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-components

I'm new on using Unity, and I'm trying to use a sprite as a collision trigger.
But my OnTriggerEnter2d  won't trigger.
Here are the infos:

main character info
[image: main character info]

collision sprite used as trigger info 
[image: sprite use as trigger]

And code for the newPlatformRow script attached to the main character

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewPlatformRow : MonoBehaviour {

    private float leftPlatformX = -12f; //de unde incepe platforma din stanga
    private float rightPlatformX = 3.123f; // de unde incepe platforma din dreapta
    private float rowDistance = -5f; //distanta dintre randurile de platforme

    private float leftPlatformWidth; //acestea vor fi calculate random pt fiecare rand nou
    private float rightPlatformWidth;





    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        //Debug.Log("why wont you work ;_;");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //Debug.Log("why wont you work ;_;");
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D other)
    {

        Debug.Log("why wont you work ;_;");

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("newPlatformRow"))
        {

            Vector3 newLeftPlaformPosition;
            Vector3 newRightPlaformPosition;

            var leftPlatform = GameObject.Find("LeftWallPlatform");
            var rightPlatform = GameObject.Find("RightWallPlatform");

            newLeftPlaformPosition = new Vector3(leftPlatform.transform.position.x, leftPlatform.transform.position.y + rowDistance, leftPlatform.transform.position.z);
            newRightPlaformPosition = new Vector3(rightPlatform.transform.position.x, rightPlatform.transform.position.y + rowDistance, rightPlatform.transform.position.z);

            Transform leftPlatformTransform = leftPlatform.transform;
            Transform rightPlatformTransform = rightPlatform.transform;

            Transform newLeftPlatform = Instantiate(leftPlatformTransform, newLeftPlaformPosition, leftPlatformTransform.rotation) as Transform;
            Transform newRightPlatform = Instantiate(rightPlatformTransform, newLeftPlaformPosition, rightPlatformTransform.rotation) as Transform;

            newLeftPlatform.parent = leftPlatformTransform.parent;
            newRightPlatform.parent = rightPlatformTransform.parent;

        }
    }
}
```

Not that the:       `Debug.Log("why wont you work ;_;");` it's never called

full scene info:
[image]

I really can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have misspelled `void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collider2D other)`.
It should actually be `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Note that capital **D** here. All the names for triggers and colliders like `OnMouseDown()` work the same way - they must have the exact same name, case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking isTrigger checkbox in material component.